¿Cómo hacer que un Button dentro del formulario sea redondo?
Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un botón de mi formulario sea redondo?
Gracias de antemano.

En que tecnologia? winforms, WPF, UWP,etc?

winforms de visual basic

Recuerdo que en VB6 lo hice con imágenes, misma técnica se hacía en la web antigua. Seguramente algo así podría funcionar

Se puede hacer con una imagen png con fondo transparente, pero no quiero usar esa técnica. Yo también lo hice en vb6 pero llamando a API's de sistema con funciones que lo hacían. Me pregunto si hay ahora algo parecido ya incluido dentro del entorno...

Para hacer que un botón  dentro del formulario sea redondo, puedes usar la propiedad Region para que adopte una forma circular
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

    Public Class Form
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    
            Dim radius As Integer = Math.Min(myButton.Width, myButton.Height) / 2
            Dim circlePath As New GraphicsPath()
            circlePath.AddEllipse(0, 0, 2 * radius, 2 * radius)

            myButton.Region = New System.Drawing.Region(circlePath)
    
    
        End Sub
    End Class


Muchas gracias, esto funciona bien. Un saludo.

La única forma que he encontrado de hacer esto, es colocando una imagen PNG con fondo transparente y forma de circulo en el centro con el dibujo dentro.
Así es la única forma que le veo yo de hacer esto.
